# Cannot convert argument of type 'URLRequest?' to expected argument type 'GADRequest??'

Tags: swift, admob

I'm having trouble determining the cause of this error in my application. Am I missing some declaration? Here is a
[Screenshot from Xcode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX89F.png)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

class Page1: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    var counter: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "6splash.png")!)

        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        let request = GADRequest()

        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
        interstitial.load(request)
    }

    //Interstitial button actions
    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        if counter % 15 == 0 {
            if interstitial?.isReady != nil {
                interstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        counter += 1
    }

    func createAndLoadInterstitial() {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-6626761084276338/7997080801")
        interstitial?.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial?.loadRequest(request as? URLRequest ?? URLRequest())
    }

    // MARK: GADInterstitialDelegate implementation
    func interstitial(_ interstitial: GADInterstitial, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ interstitial: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

}
```

I used to code primarily in Objective-C and I'm new to Swift. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the `as? URLRequest ?? URLRequest()`

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the error. However, when I tried launching again I get "Command failed due to signal: Abort Trap: 6". I deleted the above and replaced 'loadRequest' with load.

Comment: Fixed the issue, I just deleted 'import GoogleMobileAds' since it was already imported by Firebase.